# Can -phobia words be plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can you use a word ending in `-phobia` as a plural, in the following context:

> Their anachrophobias led them to running away from the fake spider.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a shared characteristic, there's only one of them... so, *their phobias...* would be one thing, but *their (shared) arachnophobia...* is something else. There's only one phobia, after all.

I think there's only a reason to use a plural if there's a material difference that makes the (*thing*) different. So, *their skin colour meant they burned easily* versus *their skin colours...* is simply a way of saying if they were identical or not. Given that you're talking about a class of phobia that covers both people, the singular would be appropriate.

(c/f *their nationality* if you want another example - if they were both German, you wouldn't say *nationalities*, as there remains only one nationality in play).